# sublime text ctrl+p opens print dialog

Tags: sublime-text

I'm using Sublime Text 2 in Ubuntu and on my Mac hitting command+p it lets me quickly select which file I want to open.

In Ubuntu hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> opens a print dialog.  How can I disable that functionality in Ubuntu for Sublime Text?

Comment: This is odd, because I'm almost certain Sublime Text doesn't have printing. That's one of my only complaints about it, actually :) Could you please check if you have any additional packages installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> gives me the following output:

[image]

What I would suggest is to look for any shortcuts changed in the Keyboard options (System Settings). Maybe there is one that was set to that combination.

Secondly I would check Sublime to see if it has the default bindings:

[image]

Just in case you or someone changed some of them.

As mentioned by Goddard, make sure your default USER binding has the following line exactly like this:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+p"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "goto", "show_files": true} }
```

that should solve the problem as tested by Goddard.

Comment: This is what mine said { "keys": ["ctrl+p"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "goto", "show_files": true} },

Comment: for some reason I had to put the key bindings in the - User area { "keys": ["ctrl+p"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "goto", "show_files": true} }

Comment: @Goddard I am sorry for not adding that to the answer but yes, mine says the same in the USER default. Is this the one you are saying?

Comment: @Goddard did it solve the problem?. If yes I will edit my answer to include such information.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I had to put my Key Bindings in the User settings folder for it to work.

Strange.  If you run into this problem try

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+p"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "goto", "show_files": true} }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2pdf plugin, remove that plugin.